# IOS App is closing at allowing to access to Adress Book

Tags: ios, permissions

My application contains a request for accessing to Address Book. As I press "Allow" button in the alert, the app is closing. Where may be mistake ? There is the code:

```
func getContactFromCNContact() -> [CNContact] {
        let contactStore = CNContactStore()
        let keysToFetch = [
            CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName),
            CNContactGivenNameKey,
            CNContactMiddleNameKey,
            CNContactFamilyNameKey,
            CNContactEmailAddressesKey,
            CNContactPhoneNumbersKey,
            CNContactImageDataKey,
        ] as [Any]
        
        var allContainers: [CNContainer] = []
        do {
            allContainers = try contactStore.containers(matching: nil) 
        
        var results: [CNContact] = []
        
        for container in allContainers {
            
            let fetchPredicate = CNContact.predicateForContactsInContainer(withIdentifier: container.identifier)
            do {
                let containerResults = try contactStore.unifiedContacts(matching: fetchPredicate, keysToFetch: keysToFetch as! [CNKeyDescriptor])
                results.append(contentsOf: containerResults)
            } catch {
                print("Error fetching results for container")
            }
        }
        return results
    }
```

Comment: post what error your console is showing..

Comment: the problem is that there is no error, it appeared after updating it to AppStore, there is not any problem in simulator and my own phone where i test my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have usage description for key `NSContactsUsageDescription` in you `Info.plist` and it's not empty.

Comment: Like that ? Privacy - Contacts Usage Description - Allow Contact Access

Comment: @elmira seems fine. if that's not the case, and crash happens only on appstore version, you can check out crash reports in Xcode - Window - Organizer - Select your app - Crashes. You need an account with access to developer.apple.com of your app to be logged in the xcode.

Comment: Is this parameter right? App Uses Non-Exempt Encryption-No. If i use Address Book in my App

Comment: @elmira you may use it in an other part of your app(most probably you don't), but for Address Book it's not needed.

Comment: Thank u for your answer! The problem is resolved :)